# How to alias column into another operation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to use the Elias column startdate  into anthor operation to calculate

```
CASE WHEN GETDATE() > detail.PeriodEndDate  THEN  GETDATE() 
                 ELSE detail.PeriodEndDate
        END as StartDate,

          CASE
                 WHEN usrPlan.PackagePlanId = 1  THEN  DATEADD(month, 1,  StartDate)
                 ELSE  DATEADD(YEAR, 1,  StartDate)
        END as EndDate,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CROSS APPLY` to define the alias in the `FROM` clause.  Then it is available throughout the query:

```
SELECT . . .,
       v.StartDate,
       (CASE WHEN up.PackagePlanId = 1 THEN  DATEADD(month, 1, v.StartDate)
             ELSE  DATEADD(YEAR, 1,  v.StartDate)
        END) as EndDate,
FROM usrPlan up . . .
     detail d . . . 
     CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN GETDATE() > d.PeriodEndDate THEN  GETDATE() 
                   ELSE d.PeriodEndDate
              END)
      ) v(StartDate)
```

Note that I added table aliases so the query is easier to write and read.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is to use a CTE to define the startdate column then use it in a subsequent query - this avoids code duplication.

So, something like:

```
; with r as (
SELECT                  *
                        , CASE  WHEN GETDATE() > detail.PeriodEndDate  THEN  GETDATE() 
                                ELSE detail.PeriodEndDate
                            END as StartDate
    FROM                [sourceTable]
)
SELECT                  *
                        , CASE  WHEN PackagePlanId = 1  THEN  DATEADD(month, 1,  StartDate)
                                ELSE  DATEADD(YEAR, 1,  StartDate)
                            END as EndDate
    FROM                r
```